# FluentNHibernate - Map a collection of sibling objects where one sibling holds a collection of the other

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, has-many

I have a collection of objects like this

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    public virtual long ApplicationConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationParameters ApplicationParameters { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ApplicationParameters> ApplicationParametersHistory { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationParameters
{
    public virtual int ApplicationParametersId { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual int Status { get; set; }
}

public class Site
{
    public virtual int SiteId { get; set; }
}
```

The way I want my model to work is that they are all bound together by my site object.  My business logic ensures that one `ApplicationParameters` is "active" and the rest are held within the History collection.

My problem comes when mapping these together with Fluent.  I have something like this

```
public class ApplicationConfigurationMap : ClassMap<ApplicationConfiguration>
{
    public ApplicationConfigurationMap()
    {
        Table("MerchantApplicationConfigurations");

        Id(x => x.ApplicationConfigurationId, "MerchantApplicationConfigurationId").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References<Site>(x => x.Site, "SiteId");

        References<ApplicationParameters>(x => x.ApplicationParameters, "ApplicationParametersId");
    }
}
```

But, how do I map my collection to pick up all the `ApplicationParameters` with Status 4 where the siblings have the same SiteId?  I know I can use `.Where("Status = 4")` but the rest of the mapping I'm not sure about.

**EDIT**

I need to clarify my design a bit.

A site is an external object used in legacy systems, so I cant alter it.  When creating these applications (a paper application, not a software application), I have to retain a complete history of all changes.  I broke the application out into a bunch of different pieces, and this configuration object is the base for the side of the application that we configure (pricing, fees, etc).

The way this system is going to work is that every part can be edited, and when it is, I create a new record with an active status and then the previous item(s) with a non-historical status are set to historical.  This way, only one record for each site is active at a given time.

I am pulling my data back by site, because I can always select the active components for that site.  If I bind my application pieces to the `ApplicationConfiguration` it means the base object can no longer follow my historical preservation model.  I also want to avoid pulling back all the pieces separately and building a DTO.

I didn't want to attach everything to the `Site` object because it's used in other applications that share this codebase.  This data model is used only within an administration application, so I wanted to keep it separate from the Site object, which is used in the admin and client applications.

Comment: Is there a reason why ApplicationParameters cannot have a foreign-key into ApplicationConfiguration instead of referencing a Site? The required way of mapping doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: My application works by creating a new record any time an edit occurs to preserve history.  I can't tie the object back to the parent, because if the parent is "edited", the link would be to the historical version instead of the "currently active" version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHibernate, when mapping a collection of entities, you have to provide a key column in the collection table that references back to the parent table. `.Where("")` just provides additional filtering on top of that.

In your case, if a list of `ApplicationParameters` belongs to `ApplicationConfiguration` then it should have `ApplicationConfigurationId` column.

If you need to tie objects through `SiteId` then you should move `ApplicationParametersHistory` to the `Site` entity.

Now your model is represented differently in your classes and in your DB. So, if you are able to reorganize your model a bit then you can use the standard way of mapping.

Comment: I edited the OP to explain my design a little more.  I was afraid I might have to do a hard link between the `ApplicationConfiguration` and its sub parts.  I wanted to avoid that to ensure that everything can follow my update model.

Comment: I ended up creating a View that joins the two tables on `SiteId`, picks out the `ApplicationParamtersId` from my table `where Status = 4` along with the `ApplicationConfigurationId`, and then I did a `HasManyToMany` across my view.

Comment: That's a good solution, I was thinking about many-to-many as well, but I didn't have understanding of your app to suggest something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HasMany method to map your collection..

```
HasMany(x => x.ApplicationParametersHistory).Where("Status = 4");
```

Is this what you're after?

Comment: The site ID has to be the same for both objects.